# Creating Cloud free images out of a MOD09A1 MODIS image in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, masking, cloud-cover

How can I mask clouds in a MODIS\MOD09A1 images in GEE?
I know I should do sth with the "Bitmask for QA", but how?

```
var myImgCln = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09A1")
    .filterMetadata(???
```

Answer (score 8):

I haven't actually worked with MODIS, but it looks like most other image collections in EE. The images contains a QA band, `StateQA`, with data about clouds/shadow/etc. The catalog contains a description of which bits contains which information:

> ```
> Bits 0-1: Cloud state
>     0: Clear
>     1: Cloudy
>     2: Mixed
>     3: Not set, assumed clear
> Bit 2: Cloud shadow
>     0: No
>     1: Yes
> Bits 3-5: Land/water flag
>     0: Shallow ocean
>     1: Land
>     2: Ocean coastlines and lake shorelines
>     3: Shallow inland water
>     4: Ephemeral water
>     5: Deep inland water
>     6: Continental/moderate ocean
>     7: Deep ocean
> Bits 6-7: Aerosol quantity
>     0: Climatology
>     1: Low
>     2: Average
>     3: High
> Bits 8-9: Cirrus detected
>     0: None
>     1: Small
>     2: Average
>     3: High
> Bit 10: Internal cloud algorithm flag
>     0: No cloud
>     1: Cloud
> Bit 11: Internal fire algorithm flag
>     0: No fire
>     1: Fire
> Bit 12: MOD35 snow/ice flag
>     0: No
>     1: Yes
> Bit 13: Pixel is adjacent to cloud
>     0: No
>     1: Yes
> Bit 14: BRDF correction performed data
>     0: No
>     1: Yes
> Bit 15: Internal snow mask
>     0: No snow
>     1: Snow
> ```

The below code uses a little utility function to extract the values for a range of bits. A mask with "Deep inland water" would be `bitwiseExtract(image, 3, 5).eq(5)`.

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09A1").first()
var qa = image.select('StateQA')
var cloudState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 1) 
var cloudShadowState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 2)
var cirrusState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8, 9)
var mask = cloudState.eq(0) // Clear
  .and(cloudShadowState.eq(0)) // No cloud shadow
  .and(cirrusState.eq(0)) // No cirrus
var maskedImage = image.updateMask(mask)  

Map.addLayer(image, {min: 0, max: 6000}, 'unmasked', false)
Map.addLayer(maskedImage, {min: 0, max: 6000}, 'masked')

/**
 * Utility to extract bitmask values. 
 * Look up the bit-ranges in the catalog.
 * 
 * value - ee.Number or ee.Image to extract from.
 * fromBit - int or ee.Number with the first bit.
 * toBit - int or ee.Number with the last bit (inclusive). 
 *         Defaults to fromBit.
 */
function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined) toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/06804ee80db139b931c2aa6329fa4c8b