Extracting QA bits for cloud mask with MOD09GA state 1km band using Google Earth Engine
I'm working on code for detecting fog and low stratus (FLS) using the QA bits from the state_1km band of the MOD09GA.061 product. I'm trying to select pixels classified as clouds (bit 0-1 Cloud State: "Cloudy" and "Mixed") and removes pixels with the presence of high cirrus clouds (bit 8-9 Cirrus detected: "none").
//Function to apply the bitmask and extract the cloud state, excluding cirrus

function maskClouds(image) {
  var state = image.select('state_1km');
  // Define the bits representing the cloud state (Bits 0-1)
  var cloudStateBits = state.rightShift(0).bitwiseAnd(3);
  // Create a mask for Cloudy (1) and Mixed (2) states
  var cloudMask = cloudStateBits.eq(1).or(cloudStateBits.eq(2));
  // Define the bits representing cirrus detection (Bits 8-9)
  var cirrusBits = state.rightShift(8).bitwiseAnd(3);
  // Create a mask to exclude cirrus (values different from 0)
  var noCirrusMask = cirrusBits.eq(0);
  // Apply the combined mask to the image
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask).updateMask(noCirrusMask);
}

// Initialize the MOD09GA image collection
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD09GA')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000, 2010, 'year'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 12, 'month'))
  .select('state_1km')
  .filterBounds(PESM)
  .map(maskClouds);

// Select a sample of 5 images for visualization and verification
var sample = modis.limit(5);

// Function to print the bit values in a specific region
function printCloudStateBits(image) {
  var cloudStateBits = image.select('state_1km').rightShift(0).bitwiseAnd(3);
  var cirrusBits = image.select('state_1km').rightShift(8).bitwiseAnd(3);
  
  // Reduce the region to obtain the bit values
  var bitValues = cloudStateBits.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
    geometry: PESM,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).getInfo();
  
  var cirrusValues = cirrusBits.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
    geometry: PESM,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).getInfo();
  
  print('Cloud state bits for image:', image.id().getInfo(), bitValues);
  print('Cirrus state bits for image:', image.id().getInfo(), cirrusValues);
  
  // Add the image to the map for visualization
  Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['state_1km']}, 'Cloud State ' + image.id().getInfo());
}

// Apply the function to each image in the sample
sample.evaluate(function(images) {
  images.features.forEach(function(image) {
    var img = ee.Image(image.id);
    printCloudStateBits(img);
  });
});

// Center the map on the region of the Serra do Mar State Park
Map.centerObject(PESM, 8);


When selecting a sample of 5 images, I noticed that the mask is not being applied correctly, and I am not sure what the error is.
I am sharing the necessary Asset for the location (PESM). See further description of the State QA:


This might give you an idea how you can do that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349401/154371

@DanielWiell The code works fine. Thank you very much!
